# Finding the limit of $a_{n} = \frac{n!}{\left(\frac{2}{7} + 1\right)\left(\frac{2}{7} + 2\right)\ldots\left(\frac{2}{7} + n\right)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

My task was to prove that the limit in the title exists and to calculate it. First I showed that the sequence is monotonically decreasing $\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} = \frac{n+1}{\frac{2}{7} + n + 1} < 1\right)$ and it's obvious that $a_{n} > 0$ for all $n$. Therefore, by the Monotone Convergence theorem $(a_n)_{n \geq 1}$ must converge.

My first idea was to use the relation I obtained earlier between $a_{n+1}$ and
$a_{n}$: $a_{n+1} = \frac{n+1}{\frac{2}{7} + n + 1} \cdot a_{n}$ and passing the limit on both sides, but I arrive at the trivial equality that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n}$.

My second idea was to rationalize the denominator to see if a more familiar expression will arise, here is what I arrived at:
$$a_{n} = \frac{7^n \cdot n!}{(2+7 \cdot 1)(2 + 7 \cdot 2)...(2 + 7 \cdot n)}$$ which didn't help.

If it is of any help, the first exercise was to study the convergence of: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{(2x+1)...(2x+n)} \text{ for } x \in (0, +\infty)$$ I determined that it converges when $x \in \left(\frac{1}{2}, \infty\right)$ by [Raabe-Duhammel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Raabe%E2%80%93Duhamel%27s_test) and diverges otherwise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{1}{a_n}=\frac{1}{n!}\prod_{k=1}^n\left(k+\frac{2}{7}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{2}{7k}\right).
$$
Therefore we infer that
$$
\log(1/a_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(1+\frac{2}{7k}\right).
$$
As $\log(1+x)\geq x/2$ for $x\in[0,1]$, we have
$$
\log(1/a_n)\geq\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{7k},
$$
and as the LHS diverges for $n\to\infty$, we infer $\log(1/a_n)\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence $a_n\to 0$.

Comment: "and as the LHS diverges"  I think you mean RHS.

Comment: logs can be avoided if we note that for $x_k\ge0$, $\prod\limits_{k=1}^n(1+x_k)\ge1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k$

Answer (score 7):

$$
\begin{align}
a_n
&=\frac{n!}{\left(1+\frac27\right)\left(2+\frac27\right)\cdots\left(n+\frac27\right)}\tag{1a}\\
&\le\frac1{(n+1)^{2/7}}\tag{1b}\\
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ given
$\text{(1b):}$ apply inequality $(4)$ below

Therefore,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0\tag2
$$

---

**Justification for $\bf{(1b)}$**

For $0\le x\le1$,
$$
\begin{align}
1+\frac xk&\ge\left(1+\frac1k\right)^x\tag{3a}\\
k+x&\ge k^{1-x}(k+1)^x\tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a):}$ [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality#Real_exponent) for exponents in $[0,1]$
$\text{(3b):}$ multiply both sides by $k$
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^n(k+x)
&\ge\prod_{k=1}^nk^{1-x}(k+1)^x\tag{4a}\\
&=n!^{1-x}(n+1)!^x\tag{4b}\\[9pt]
&=n!\,(n+1)^x\tag{4c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a):}$ apply $(3)$
$\text{(4b):}$ exponentiation distributes over products
$\text{(4c):}$ $(n+1)!=n!(n+1)$

Note that equality holds in $(4)$ when $x=0$ or $x=1$.

Comment: I got a downvote, presumably for citing Gautschi's Inequality. I have simplified the inequality in $(1)$ so that it only relies on Bernoulli's Inequality, which is much simpler.

Comment: Downvoting wasn't in any case deserved and any different way is good to know. That being said this one is a a very nice proof!

Comment: I have fixed a typo and +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: thanks for catching that typo. The only thing wrong with using Gautschi’s inequality is that it deals with the Gamma function, and that causes anxiety when people are not familiar with Gamma. I should prove a version that deals with factorials, since they are just $\Gamma(\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $c$ be any strictly positive real number, such as $2/7.$ Define
$$
a_n = \frac{n!}{(c+1)(c+2)\cdots(c+n)} =
\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{c+k} = \prod_{k=1}^n(1-b_k),
$$
where
$$
b_k = \frac{c}{c+k} \quad (k = 1, 2, \ldots).
$$

Because $0<b_k<1$ for all $k,$ the infinite product
$\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1-b_k)$ converges (to a strictly positive limit)
or diverges to $0$ according as the infinite series
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k$ converges or diverges (to $\infty$).

(See, for example: Tom M. Apostol, *Mathematical Analysis*, 2nd ed. 1974,
Theorem 8.55; or Peter Duren, *Invitation to Classical Analysis*, 2012,
Chapter 5, Theorem 1.)

Because
$$
b_k > \frac{c/2}{k} \quad (k > c),
$$
and because $\sum_{k=1}^\infty1/k$ diverges, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k$ diverges;
therefore $\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1-b_k) = 0.$
That is, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0.$

Answer (score 2):

Using that

$$\left(\frac{2}{7} + 1\right)\left(\frac{2}{7} + 2\right)\ldots\left(\frac{2}{7} + n\right)= n!+\frac27\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{n!}i+\ldots\ge n!\left(1+\frac27\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}i\right)$$

by divergence of the harmonic series, we have

$$a_{n} = \frac{n!}{\left(\frac{2}{7} + 1\right)\left(\frac{2}{7} + 2\right)\ldots\left(\frac{2}{7} + n\right)}\le \frac{1}{1+\frac27\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}i}\to 0$$

Answer (score 2):

If, as @Calum Gilhooley did, we make the problem more general
$$a_n = \frac{n!}{(c+1)(c+2)\cdots(c+n)} =
\frac{n!}{(c+1)_n}=\Gamma (c+1)\,\frac{ \Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (n+1+c)}$$ Taking logarithms and using twice Stirling approximation
$$\log \left(\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (n+1+c)}\right)=-c \log (n)-\frac{c (c+1)}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
Exponentiate
$$\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (n+1+c)}=n^{-c} \left(1-\frac{c (c+1)}{2
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)\tag 1$$

So, since $c>0$, the limit
$$\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{limit }}a_n=\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{limit }}\frac{\Gamma(c+1)}{n^c}\to 0$$

But $(1)$ gives also a good approximation of $a_n$. Using $c=\frac 27$ and $n=10$, it gives $0.457462$ while the exact value is $0.457755$ (relative error of $0.06$%).